# Mysqldb returns Null for one column that is not Null

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mariadb, mysql-python

I have a script that is supposed to check a status field in the database by another script before deciding to do some other work. We have multiple similar types of devices and each type has its own table. This script is checking three of these different device types and is accessing a module I created for the database functions. When the first device type runs, everything works great, but the next two return Null, which comes out to None, since this is python. The code is the same for all three, I just submit the device name and type to the function. I've had it print the sql query it uses and it works if I run it directly in SQL. I also had it select the whole row instead of just the single column and all other columns come back correct, but that one column is still Null. I've checked the database structure and other than the device types have different numbers of columns, they're essentially identical, and this column in particular is the same across tables. I have another almost identical function that pulls a different column and that one works across all tables. The datatype on this column is text and I have tried varchar and received the same results.

Database Function:

```
def getStatus(self, target, type):
    sql = 'SELECT `status` FROM `' + type + 's` WHERE `' + type + 'id` = \'' + target + '\''
    cursor = self.data_base.cursor()
    try:
        test = cursor.execute(sql)
        data = cursor.fetchone()
        print data[0]
        return data[0]
    except Exception as e:
        print "Error: " + str(e)
```

Main Script(generic version, both are the same except different device types):

```
for device in devices:

    ip = db.getIp(device, "device type")
    status = db.getStatus(device, 'device type')
    print status
```

For one type of device, both prints work correctly, for the other, I get None in both places.
Database is MariaDB 5.5.56 on RedHat 7.4

(From Comment)

```
CREATE TABLE vgws (
    vgwid varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
    ip varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
    siteid varchar(8) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
    vendor varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL, 
    version varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL, 
    status text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci, 
    PRIMARY KEY (vgwid), 
    UNIQUE KEY ip (ip)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

The generated query is

```
SELECT status FROM vgws WHERE vgwid = 'DEVICE NAME'
```

Comment: Please show us the generated SQL.  And `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Sharing what I can. It's not exactly like this, but the pertinent parts are for both tables:

    CREATE TABLE `vgws` (
     `vgwid` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
     `ip` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
     `siteid` varchar(8) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
     `vendor` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
     `version` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
     `status` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
     PRIMARY KEY (`vgwid`),
     UNIQUE KEY `ip` (`ip`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: The generated query is:
    SELECT `status` FROM `vgws` WHERE `vgwid` = 'DEVICE NAME'

Comment: Hmm... I seem to not be getting the code formatting right. Sorry about that.

Comment: (Limited formatting in Comments.  I edited your Question for you.)

Comment: If the table is short enough, show us the entire contents.  Also, you mentioned `'DEVICE NAME'` -- did that print?  And what value worked the other way?

Comment: Thanks for updating for me. I'm still pretty new to actually writing things on here. 

It's proprietary data, unfortunately, so I can't share the actual contents. DEVICE NAME is just a filler for what the code would put there. It would be the actual device name in the single quotes.

Comment: That query is returning only one column, and it is `NULL`.  So I conclude that you have a `NULL` for `status` where `vgwid = 'DEVICE NAME'`.  If I misinterpreted your question, please clarify.

Comment: That's my problem. The status is not Null in the database. If I run the query directly in SQL I get the correct status. If I run it on this table in my script I get Null, but if I run it on another table that is structurally almost identical other than names and a few added columns, I get a correct status.

Comment: Your `CREATE TABLE` says, by omission, that it is NULLable.

Comment: Yeah, I did think that might be affecting it somehow, but every row does have something entered for status. And, again, if I run the sql that is generated by the script directly, it works. I appreciate you taking a look, though, because several people have looked at it here and are at a loss.

Comment: Let's see the output from `SELECT * FROM vgws WHERE vgwid = 'DEVICE NAME'`